# Spring MVC ThemeChangeInterceptor do not change theme

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, themes, interceptor

I am stuck at something really painful.
I am trying to use the theming of Spring WebMVC.

This is the end of my web-context.xml file :

```
<beans:bean id="themeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" >
    <beans:property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <beans:property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" >
    <beans:property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="interceptors">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

In my header file, I have something like :

```
<span style="float: right">
        <a href="?theme=default">Default</a>
        |
        <a href="?theme=other">Other</a>
</span>
```

And to finish, my html head has (imported in all views) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code="css"/>" type="text/css" />
```

I got the two properties files in src/main/resources, which leads to my css. For example in theme-default.properties, there is :

```
css=static/css/dev.css
```

My css are in src/webapp/static/css/.
When I load the website for the first time, the theme is default, so I think that the property files and the css are correctly found by the Theme resolver.
But when I click on Default or Other in the header, nothing happens.

Do you know where the problem is ?

Thank you very much beforehand !
Olivier.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are registering the interceptor wrongly. If you are configuring Spring-MVC by using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` then having a separate `handlerMapping` will not work as a default handlerMapping is register by the custom `mvc` namespace also. Try registering it this way instead:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I finally extended the class ThemeResolver itself in order to have the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `<mvc:interceptors>` declaration. And your ThemeChangeInterceptor bean should be there

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="theme" />
        </beans:bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I finally extended the class ThemeResolver itself in order to have the behavior I expected. I think some of the interceptors implemented in my services module came into conflict with the ThemeChangeInterceptor...